# PHP Header download PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf

I've made a page where you can go and write text in a "textarea" and then when you click download you download that file as a .txt file. I've done the same thing to some other extensions and that is working fine. But it won't work with .PDF, nothing I read works. Here is the snippet I use for the .PDF downloading:

```
<?php

if($fileFormat == ".pdf"){

$content = $_POST['text'];
$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$nameAndExt = $name.".pdf";
print strip_tags($content);

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$nameAndExt.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ');
}

?>
```

I'm grateful for any answear, thanks!

Comment: i think that doesn't work with just the modified header. you need a html2pdf converter plugin like this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/

Answer (score 1):

```
// hold the filename for use elsewhere so you don't have to append .pdf every time
$filename = "$id.pdf";

// create the file
$pdf->output( $filename );

// set up the headers
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

// push the buffer to the client and exit
ob_clean();
flush();

// read the file and push to the output stream
readfile( $filename );

// remove the file from the filesystem
unlink( $filename );
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a class like TCPDF, see http://www.tcpdf.org/. I used it couple of times and it's quite nice (open source).